# MySQL getting total sum of all rows using cases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which records values in a database when a user has paid by voucher.  It records the voucher value.  I need to get a total sum of all voucher values broken down by the voucher amount.  The query I currently have is below.  However the `butchery_class_voucher_155` and `butchery_class_voucher_135` are always returned as 0.

Please help to solve this problem.

```
select 
case 
    when voucher_value = '155.00' 
    then round(sum(voucher_value/1.2), 2) 
    else 0.00 end 
as butchery_class_voucher_155,
case 
    when voucher_value = '10.00' 
    then round(sum(voucher_value/1.2), 2) 
    else 0.00 end 
as shop_voucher,
case when voucher_value = '135.00'      
    then round(sum(voucher_value/1.2), 2) 
    else 0.00 end 
as butchery_class_voucher_135,
ifnull(round(sum(final_price/1.2), 2),0.00) as paidbycard,
ifnull(round(sum(transfer_fee/1.2), 2),0.00) as transfer_fee 
    from `bookings` 
where `location_id` = 6
```

Comment: is `voucher_value` a text field?

Comment: No, it's a decimal `decimal(9,2)`

Comment: Then why are you doing a text comparison?

Comment: @SunKnight0 - even if I use ` = 155` I still get 0.00 as the result.

Comment: @SunKnight0: shouldn't matter as MySQL will do an implicit conversion

Comment: @PaulF: It does matter for performance

Comment: @V4n1ll4: Try to do a simple select query and see if you get any records `SELECT  voucher_value FROM bookings WHERE voucher_value=155 AND location_id=6`

Comment: @SunKnight0: I think you will find that the conversion of the string to decimal will be done prior to this query, rather than decimal to string during the query - so any performance issue will be immeasurably small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have the sum() call within a case, even though the cases (or ifs) should be inside the sum(). With your current code, if the 1st record has a voucher_value of 10, then only the shop_voucher expression will give you any result other than zero.

```
select 
    round(sum(if(voucher_value=155,voucher_value/1.2,0)), 2) as butchery_class_voucher_155,
    ...
    from `bookings` 
where `location_id` = 6
```

You need to consider one more thing: where exactly you put your rounding function. You can sum the results first and then round that (this is what is used in my code above), or you can apply the rounding at each and every division.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is failing is due to the way you have set up your case statement. You've written a query to give you the sum if the voucher_value equals a certain value, or to give you zero. On the last row the query analyzes, it will only compare that voucher value, and the others will return as 0.

To fix this, you need to adjust your `SUM()` function to add the voucher value in the case that the value matches, otherwise to add 0:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN voucher_value = 155 THEN (voucher_value / 1.2) ELSE 0 END), 2) AS butchery_class_voucher_155...
```

And so on.